# bash: sketchbook: No such file or directory

Tags: ros, rosseral-arduino

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have the package and the IDE installed, now I want to copy ros_lib from the rosserial package to the sketchbook library folder which is has been created.

I used this command lines;-

> roscd rosserial_arduino/libraries

> cp -r ros_lib /libraries/ros_lib

but unfortunately I get this error msg

> bash: sketchbook: No such file or directory

Why is this happen?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/129916/bash:-sketchbook:-no-such-file-or-directory/) by [Ross Marry](https://answers.ros.org/users/8466/ross-marry/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-02-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kamiccolo](https://answers.ros.org/users/5346/kamiccolo/) on 2014-02-17**:
Are You sure, there is a `sketchbook` directory in Your current dir? You might just did a typo or something simple like that :)
$ ls | grep sketchbook

**Comment by [Ross Marry](https://answers.ros.org/users/8466/ross-marry/) on 2014-02-17**:
There is nothing came out. Sorry, I'm still new to this. How can I get it into my current directory?

**Comment by [Kamiccolo](https://answers.ros.org/users/5346/kamiccolo/) on 2014-02-17**:
Sorry, You should provide more information to get a clear answer. Why don't You try copy those files using    Desktop Environment and File Manager like Nautilus or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are supposed to replace  with the directory of your Arduino sketchbook (typically this defaults to ~/sketchbook)

EDIT: Furthermore, that's not the right way to setup rosserial_arduino, see http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/Arduino%20IDE%20Setup

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2014-02-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1